# Accordion for a Boostrap row in a 6-column layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion, portfolio

I'm using Bootstrap to make a 6-column layout portfolio website. Every row (with a fixed height) contains 6 elements. I would like the lower row to move down (of a relative amount of pixels) when one of the six elements in the upper one is clicked. In the blank space between the rows a div with contents should appear also.

I guess this has something to do with the built-in accordion function of Bootstrap but it is conceived to operate with whole rows instead of individual elements inside a row.

This is an example of the code I'm dealing with:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 1 A</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 2 A</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 3 A</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 4 A</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 5 A</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 6 A</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 1 B</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 2 B</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 3 B</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 4 B</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 5 B</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 6 B</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

These are example images:

Before click on one of the elements
[image]

After click on one of the elements
[image]

Many thanks to everyone in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to modify the below to suit your needs but this works: https://jsfiddle.net/y91Ly246/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row first">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 1 A</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 2 A</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 3 A</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 4 A</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 5 A</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 6 A</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  CONTENT!
</div>
<div class="row second">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 1 B</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 2 B</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 3 B</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 4 B</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 5 B</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <p><a href="#">column 6 B</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".content").hide();
$(".first > div > p > a").click(function() {
    $(".content").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your support! How can I afford the accordion animation effect too?

Comment: You can use .toggleSlide or an array of others, here's some documentation: [http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

Comment: @DavideGiorgetta Be sure to mark an answer as correct / accepted / upvoted if you find it useful - it'll help people in the future...